# Spatial sectoring of points by sum of values ​in a column (advanced cluster)

Tags: qgis, clustering

I need to sectorize some streets according to the **established size**. In the example, I have a total of 600,000 meters of streets (image 1) and I need to divide it into 5 regions with more or less 120,000 meters each (image 2).

[image]
[image]

The division needs to follow a **certain spatial logic**, as it involves streets (image 3).
I tried to do it per cluster but I couldn't.

[image]

Divisions are not always fixed. In the example, it is divided by 5, but I may need to divide by 100, 150, 200, or 300.

How do I achieve this spatial division?

The sectorization can be done with the shapefile of lines or points. To me, it does not matter.

If possible, **prioritize the entire street until the end**, instead of breaking them between 2 clusters.

I am sending both attached.

**Shapefile point:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13R8AcfQ7RyLyh24Wglwj_R_NOk_LDepe/view?usp=sharing

**Shapefile line:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_wfLs_43CES1ZAym12yPet6GCj6dHJCB/view?usp=sharing